# How to change Color of Points in Excel-Chart via VBA

Tags: excel, vba

since I'm in the process of automating chart creation for comparison between measurement and simulation data, I want the data to look exactly the same way every time someone uses the script.

For that I want the lines to be of the same color, so e.g. blue is always measured data and green is always simulated data.
I want everything on the line to be the same color, so the line, as well as the data, points themselves. Also, the data points have a frame that I need to either control the color of or get rid of completely.

For now, I use the following code:

```
'create first series (measurement)
ActiveChart.SeriesCollection.NewSeries
ActiveChart.FullSeriesCollection(1).Name = measurement_legend_title
ActiveChart.FullSeriesCollection(1).XValues = "=Peak_Torque_Values!$A$3:$A$30"
ActiveChart.FullSeriesCollection(1).Values = "=Peak_Torque_Values!$B$3:$B$30"
ActiveChart.FullSeriesCollection(1).Select

Selection.MarkerStyle = 1
With Selection.Format.Fill
    .Visible = msoTrue
    .ForeColor.RGB = RGB(0, 176, 240)
    .Solid
End With
With Selection.Format.Line
    .Visible = msoTrue
    .ForeColor.RGB = RGB(0, 176, 240)
    .Transparency = 0
End With
```

The result looks like this:

[image: How it looks right now]

Can anybody tell me how I can change the color of the marker that is now dark blue? And also, can someone tell me how I get rid of the frame around the marker? The macro recording within Excel really doesn't help me with this.

Thank you, guys!!

Edit: Picture of the legend that after first solution is still "the old way":
[image: update_legend]

Answer (score 0):

This piece of code will cycle through the data point markers and change the data point marker to red (you can change the specific color by changing the RBG() function in the code.  Note that this code references the first series.

```
Dim x As Integer
    For x = 1 To ActiveChart.FullSeriesCollection(1).Points.Count
        ActiveChart.FullSeriesCollection(1).Points(x).Select
        Selection.MarkerStyle = 2    'Sets the style/look of the marker
        With Selection.Format.Fill
            .ForeColor.RGB = RGB(255, 0, 0)  'determines the color of the marker
        End With
    Next x
```

Comment: If you want colour changes within the lines you can look up your preferred colours and can iterate through the RGB colour number by adding different values.

Comment: Hey guys, thank you for the help! I have a follow-up question: If I do this point by point, the legend is still displayed "the old way". How can I change the color in the legend itself?

Answer (score 0):

Edit your code just a little to change the chart type and you don't need to loop through points.

```
Sub Macro1()

ActiveChart.SeriesCollection.NewSeries
ActiveChart.FullSeriesCollection(1).Name = measurement_legend_title
ActiveChart.FullSeriesCollection(1).XValues = "=Peak_Torque_Values!$A$3:$A$30"
ActiveChart.FullSeriesCollection(1).Values = "=Peak_Torque_Values!$B$3:$B$30"
ActiveChart.FullSeriesCollection(1).ChartType = xlLineMarkers
ActiveChart.FullSeriesCollection(1).Select
Selection.MarkerStyle = 1
With Selection.Format.Fill
    .Visible = msoTrue
    .ForeColor.RGB = RGB(0, 176, 240)
    .Solid
End With

End Sub
```

[image]